# DHL Shipping Charges

Tags: php, xml, opencart, dhl

I am trying to get the shipping charges.
Here is my request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<p:DCTRequest xmlns:p="http://www.dhl.com" xmlns:p1="http://www.dhl.com/datatypes"  xmlns:p2="http://www.dhl.com/DCTRequestdatatypes" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.dhl.com DCT-req.xsd ">
  <GetQuote>
    <Request>
      <ServiceHeader>
        <MessageTime>2017-10-20T11:28:56.000-08:00</MessageTime>
        <MessageReference>pukka301934229934707056790226292</MessageReference>
        <SiteID>******</SiteID>
        <Password>******</Password>
      </ServiceHeader>
    </Request>
    <From>
      <CountryCode>DE</CountryCode>
      <Postalcode>10717</Postalcode>
      <City>BERLIN</City>
    </From>
    <BkgDetails>
      <PaymentCountryCode>DE</PaymentCountryCode>
      <Date>2017-10-19</Date>
      <ReadyTime>PT9H</ReadyTime>
      <DimensionUnit>CM</DimensionUnit>
      <WeightUnit>KG</WeightUnit>
      <Pieces>
        <Piece>
          <PieceID>1</PieceID>
          <Height>30</Height>
          <Depth>30</Depth>
          <Width>30</Width>
          <Weight>250</Weight>
        </Piece>
       </Pieces>
      <IsDutiable>Y</IsDutiable>
    </BkgDetails>
    <To>
      <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
      <Postalcode>60603</Postalcode>
      <City>CHICAGO</City>
    </To>
    <Dutiable>
      <DeclaredCurrency>EUR</DeclaredCurrency>
      <DeclaredValue>90</DeclaredValue>
    </Dutiable>
  </GetQuote>
</p:DCTRequest>
```

I am getting the error:

```
The requested Global Product Code and Local Product Code is not available based on origin country DE postal location and destination country US postal location for payment country DE. 
Please make sure data entered is valid before proceeding or contact our customer service.
```

But when I change

```
  <DimensionUnit>CM</DimensionUnit>
  <WeightUnit>KG</WeightUnit>
```

to

```
  <DimensionUnit>IN</DimensionUnit>
  <WeightUnit>LB</WeightUnit>
```

I get the shipping amount. But I need to send the value in CM and KG. Please help me figure out the error.

Comment: You can easily convert CM to IN by multiplying it by 2.54, KG-LB *2.21.  Know this isn't ideal, but should still be the same parcel.

Comment: @NigelRen have you worked on dhl api or atleast know a bit about the tags?

Comment: No, but I know that in the USA they tend to deal in imperial units (inches and lbs) and not metric.

Comment: okay thanks for the help :) @NigelRen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the reasons could be that you are exceeding the maximum weight limit or passing an incorrect value for the CM and KG units.

Add a lower value for the weight, start with 10 KG.